What does __code mean in Django?
What does __code mean in Django?
I'm beginner find this code, but I don't now what does name__code mean.
def get_queryset(self):
    names = self.request.query_params.get("name", None)
    if names:
        # qs = Hero.objects.filter(name=names)
        for name in names.split(self.names_separator):
            qs = Hero.objects.filter(name__code=name)
        # res = Hero.objects.get(name="Bad")
        # print(res)

            return qs

I tried to find info in enthernet, but I can't

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

This syntax is explained as part of the tutorial, which you should read when starting with a new technology: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api

Share the corresponding models.

@willeM What was wrong with the duplicate…?

I think there is too few data, there can be two reasons: a foreign key, or a custom lookup. For example one could register a code lookup to a field that takes the first two characters.

@willeM The duplicate mentions both concepts and further links to the docs for further exploration. Unless and until OP clarifies to make this more specifically answerable, I think that's a fine answer as is…

In simple words, name__code is a way to search for something specific within a field called name.

name is the field you're searching in.
__code is what you're searching for within that field.

It's like looking for a specific word (code) within a sentence (name).
For example, if name is "John Doe - ABC123", name__code would search for "ABC123" within that name.

This explanation is a bit too simplified, to the point that it's wrong.
